# Sublime text: Adding symbols to a new language definition (syntax highlighting)

Tags: sublimetext, cadence

I have written syntax highlighting for a slightly unfamiliar language (Cadence SKILL) in sublime text 2.

Its working like a charm, however I miss the feature of CTRL + R , which locates all the symbols (functions) in the present file in an easily accessible way.

Can anyone please suggest how to tell Sublime Text where to look for a pattern of function (procedure) declaration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `Default/Symbol List.tmPreferences`. You can create this preference file and specify scopes to include in the symbol list. You may also want to look at `Java/Symbol List <some specifier>.tmPreferences` for examples of a language specific symbol list. Alternatively, you can ensure the things that you want to include have the scope `entity.name.function` or `entity.name.type`.

**edit**

You will need to look at your color scheme file. These files are Plist, so you may want to use something like [PlistJsonConverter](https://github.com/facelessuser/PlistJsonConverter) to make it a little more readable (though this is more of a personal preference). In this file, you will see a number of dictionary entries. One of the keys to these entries is scope. When a matching scope is found as defined by your language definition. You will also see a "settings" key that defines details about color, font style, etc. Since you want different colors, you will need to apply different scopes. You will need to define a custom Symbol List preference file so everything gets included properly. The following is from the Java package.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Symbol List: Classes</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.java meta.class meta.class.identifier</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>showInSymbolList</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>22E489AE-989E-4A76-9C18-89944CF5013D</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You will define whatever scopes are being applied to the entries you want to appear in the list.

Comment: Thanks :)
However I am not so comfortable with "entity.name.function" etc. terminologies. Can you please share a resource to learn them? But at least I got the pointer to move ahead.

Comment: "entity.name.function" is just a scope name. I make the assumption you know what scopes are since it sounds like you wrote a syntax file. In terms of learning, for me it was browsing through the ST files and looking through the textmate docs. http://manual.macromates.com/en/ I guess for ST specifically, if I saw something happen occur differently, on a language specific basis, I started searching through those files to see how it was done.

Comment: I don't know what scopes are, however the syntax file was just made modifying the 'lisp' syntax file! 
Its working good for me now, but I guess I need to dig deep into these things if I want these advanced features to work.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Simply put, scopes are names applied to patterns matching the regular expression patterns. But yea, it's probably worthwhile to learn a bit about them if you are going to modify syntax files (or modify color schemes I suppose).

Comment: Hi there, first of all thanks to you, as I have, to a good degree understood scopes and I have achieved what I originally asked (see all the symbols in ctrl + R ).
However, I want more!
Sublime Text is not using different colors for different scopes. How do I achieve that? (FYI, I am using the cobalt theme). Thanks

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit to address the coloring.

Answer (score 0):

I too made one myself for Cadence Skill. You can try it out here

https://github.com/noisyass2/SublimeCadenceSkill

Comment: hi there, I am using your syntax highlighting now (just switched to ST3). Its far better than what I achieved. However, in the symbols List, I am seeing lot many things (like hiCreateLabel etc), how do I see only the procedure names when I press Ctrl + R?

Comment: oh that was intentional, i included all the function calls with the function declarations. but yeah, i updated it now and removed those function calls on the symbolsList (ctrl+R).